# How can I see all the questions I have posted?

Tags: support, profile-page

I would like to see all the questions I have posted. I can find questions that were interesting for my only by clicking answers in my inbox.

But maybe there is another way?

Comment: You can see them [linked here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1501700/user1501700?tab=questions)?!?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to filter them based on received answers somehow?

Comment: @ArtjomB. no, I think the OP has yet to find his profile and the info contained within.  Currently, he tries to find his old questions by looking for the notification of an answer in the inbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously have not found [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501700/vico) yet.

You can access it by clicking your profile picture in the top bar

> [image]

Similarly, you can access it by clicking on your display name most places is displayed on Stack Overflow (it is linked from your comments, your questions, and your answers)